# Spring-mvc controller returning wrong view

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, controller, spring-boot

I am developing example with Spring-boot, web and JSP as views. All works fine with path like http://127.0.0.1:8080/products or http://127.0.0.1:8080/. But if i try work with url parameters in controller it return error

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Wed Jun 15 09:15:42 EEST 2016
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   /product/WEB-INF/jsp/productshow.jsp

As you can see it try to search jsp page in  /product/WEB-INF/jsp/ instead /WEB-INF/jsp/

Here my viewResolver

```
    @Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

private ProductService productService;

@Autowired
public void setProductService(ProductService productService) {
    this.productService = productService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("products", productService.listAllProducts());
    return "products";
}

@RequestMapping("product/{id}")
public String showProduct(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("product", productService.getProductById(id));
    return "productshow";
}

}
```

Comment: It is returning exactly what you configured it to do. add `/` to your `prefix` so that it reads `/WEB-INF/jsp/`.

Comment: Thanks, it's realy help for me.